# Sort by column sub-values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

My pandas DataFrame looks something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
 Name   | Stats                     
---------------------------------------
 Bob    | { age : 42, profession: IT }
 Jill   | { age : 35, profession: Engineer }
 Patric | { age : 37, profession: Student }
---------------------------------------
```

Where `Stats` is a class and `age` and `profession` are both properties on that class.

I'd like to sort that table by one of the properties on `Stats`. For example, sort it by the person's age so that the table looks like:

```
---------------------------------------
 Name   | Stats                     
---------------------------------------
 Jill   | { age : 35, profession: Engineer }
 Patric | { age : 37, profession: Student }
 Bob    | { age : 42, profession: IT }
---------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to do that with Pandas? I've only found ways to sort by the entire column

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**
You can use `argsort` to find the appropriate ordering and pass that to `iloc`.  However, you need to create a dataframe in order to run `argsort` on the `age` column.

```
df.iloc[pd.DataFrame(df.Stats.values.tolist()).age.argsort()]

     Name                                  Stats
1    Jill  {'age': 35, 'profession': 'Engineer'}
2  Patric   {'age': 37, 'profession': 'Student'}
0     Bob        {'age': 42, 'profession': 'IT'}
```

---

After reading [**@Alexander's answer...**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469584/2336654) I came up with something that combines his idea and mine.  If anyone finds this part useful, please don't forget to upvote his answer.

```
df.iloc[np.argsort([x.get('age') for x in df.Stats])]
```

**Timing**
Small sample data

```
%timeit df.iloc[pd.DataFrame(df.Stats.values.tolist()).age.argsort()]
%timeit df.iloc[np.argsort([x.get('age') for x in df.Stats])]
%timeit df.iloc[np.argsort([x.get('age') for x in df.Stats.values.tolist()])]

1000 loops, best of 3: 756 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 207 µs per loop
```

**Setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Name='Bob Jill Patric'.split(),
    Stats=[
        dict(age=42, profession='IT'),
        dict(age=35, profession='Engineer'),
        dict(age=37, profession='Student')
    ]
))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm curious, what made you think to try df.Stats.values.tolist()? If anything, I would have expected that to add to the overhead, not reduce it

Comment: @ZainRizvi experience with this stuff is what made me think of it.  If I want to use a list comprehension, its quicker to iterate through a list than through either a pandas series or numpy array.  [**See this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40593444/2336654)

Answer (score 2):

A major point of using a dataframe is to type your columns for efficient storage and computational speed (e.g. int64, float64, object, etc).  Your data is not well structured; you should likely have a separate column for each field in `Stats`.  See [Tidy Data](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-5-tidy.html) for more info.

```
df2 = df[['Name']].assign(age=[d.get('age') for d in df['Stats']],
                          profession=[d.get('profession') for d in df['Stats']])
```

Then it is easy to work with your data.

```
>>> df2.sort_values('age')
     Name  age profession
1    Jill   35   Engineer
2  Patric   37    Student
0     Bob   42         IT
```