# Convert numpy array of shape x,y to a list of size x with every element a numpy array of shape (y,)

Tags: numpy

So if the shape is 100,10
the list should have 100 elements. Each element is a numpy array of shape (10,)

Comment: `list(arr)` makes a list of arrays; `arr.tolist()` makes a list of lists.  `tolist` is faster.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want this, OP?

Comment: @ddejohn One example when this can be useful are scenarios where you are forced to iterate over an axis of your array using a `for` loop because the loop's body can not be vectorized.

Comment: @FirefoxMetzger you can iterate over an array without needing to convert it to a list though. Can you give an explicit example? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @ddejohn Indeed you can. It will, however, be slower than via `np.split` or `np.ndarray.tolist`, because you pay the cost of creating a new `np.view` at each iteration. `tolist` and `split` can create a series of objects in one go which is slightly faster. It is a pretty niche use-case though. Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593444/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-iterate-through-a-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

Anything wrong with [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)?

Here is a quick example:

```py
import numpy as np

some_array = np.random.rand(100, 10)
list_of_arrays = [np.squeeze(x, axis=0) for x in np.split(some_array, len(some_array))]

# some assertions that it does what you ask
assert len(list_of_arrays) == 100
assert isinstance(list_of_arrays, list)
assert all([isinstance(x, np.ndarray) for x in list_of_arrays])
assert all([x.shape == (10,) for x in list_of_arrays])
```

If you are okay with a shape of `(1, 10)` you can save the list comprehension:

```py
import numpy as np

some_array = np.random.rand(100, 10)
list_of_arrays = np.split(some_array, len(some_array))
```