# How to optimize this numpy code to make it faster?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This code is working as expected and calculates cosign distance between two embeddings. But it takes a lot of time. I have tens of thousands of records to check and I am looking for a way to make it quicker.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import dot
from numpy.linalg import norm

import ast

df = pd.read_csv("https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/cosign_dist.csv")

for k, i in enumerate(df["embeddings"]):
    df["dist" + str(k)] = df.embeddings.apply(
        lambda x: dot(ast.literal_eval(x), ast.literal_eval(i))
        / (norm(ast.literal_eval(x)) * norm(ast.literal_eval(i)))
    )
```

Comment: Before your loop `df['embeddings'] = df['embeddings'].apply(ast.literal_eval)`. Now you have lists then remove all other `ast.literal_eval(...)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40593934

Comment: Can you embed a toy example of the `df` without resorting to downloading the csv file?

Comment: The embeddings list is so big that it will not display / format properly. @norok2

Comment: @shantanuo At this level it is important to know how big it is and the data types. If you provide a toy example this will tell the data types, and the size you could comment about. Even better if you'd provide a generative model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Optimized way**:

Instead of applying `ast.literal_eval` many times in a loop, load the input csv file with the needed structure at once using `converters` option to convert all `'embeddings'` column array string representation into "real" array with [`numpy.fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) routine.

```
df = pd.read_csv("https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/cosign_dist.csv", 
                 delimiter=',', usecols=["embeddings"], quotechar='"',
                 converters = {'embeddings': lambda s: np.fromstring(s[1:-1], sep=',')})
```

In the above process in my measurements `numpy.fromstring` runs in **6** times faster than `converters = {'embeddings': ast.literal_eval}`, though  the latter, in it's turn, is faster than your initial approach.

Then, to avoid multiple dataframe insertions with a new `dist<num>` column replace `for` looping with [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df] + [df.embeddings.apply(
                        lambda x: np.dot(x, arr)
                                  / (np.linalg.norm(x) * np.linalg.norm(arr))
                        ).rename(f'dist{i}')
                        for i, arr in enumerate(df["embeddings"])], axis=1)
```

The final result (a fragment of first 3 records):

```
print(df.head(3))
```

---

```
                                          embeddings     dist0     dist1  \
0  [-0.009409046731889248, 0.01787922903895378, -...  1.000000  0.824427   
1  [-0.0005574452807195485, -0.004265215713530779...  0.824427  1.000000   
2  [-0.024396933615207672, -0.0016798048745840788...  0.757717  0.762072   

      dist2     dist3     dist4     dist5     dist6     dist7     dist8  \
0  0.757717  0.761481  0.858895  0.844244  0.781320  0.830562  0.869494   
1  0.762072  0.768355  0.832918  0.813206  0.779384  0.822365  0.831671   
2  1.000000  0.775206  0.757655  0.756076  0.770092  0.766206  0.765154   

      dist9    dist10    dist11    dist12    dist13    dist14    dist15  \
0  0.824993  0.838671  0.863087  0.809240  0.839480  0.852663  0.812553   
1  0.843859  0.832757  0.846339  0.797901  0.833095  0.836512  0.794878   
2  0.756694  0.765615  0.760532  0.754582  0.759305  0.749540  0.758749   

     dist16    dist17    dist18    dist19    dist20    dist21    dist22  \
0  0.834376  0.851168  0.853374  0.831500  0.786812  0.840630  0.831902   
1  0.831882  0.829072  0.828278  0.773624  0.828781  0.814124  0.852540   
2  0.749419  0.750785  0.759364  0.776753  0.761560  0.770000  0.766988   

     dist23    dist24    dist25    dist26    dist27    dist28    dist29  \
0  0.836812  0.807903  0.822919  0.837386  0.767737  0.815725  0.807334   
1  0.799753  0.827189  0.812533  0.822119  0.788155  0.850503  0.843936   
2  0.761825  0.773761  0.764308  0.757826  0.755465  0.772704  0.766396   

     dist30    dist31    dist32    dist33    dist34    dist35    dist36  \
0  0.832612  0.835909  0.819697  0.853597  0.806614  0.805309  0.822521   
1  0.852967  0.842627  0.802803  0.860669  0.793716  0.787563  0.788239   
2  0.762748  0.763906  0.765716  0.756643  0.766686  0.772603  0.760913   

     dist37    dist38    dist39    dist40    dist41    dist42    dist43  \
0  0.831307  0.834015  0.821262  0.812144  0.853028  0.849498  0.830675   
1  0.845437  0.816868  0.833320  0.808172  0.835293  0.824654  0.856051   
2  0.760276  0.754683  0.765499  0.756421  0.755651  0.763656  0.754828   

     dist44    dist45    dist46    dist47    dist48  ...    dist50    dist51  \
0  0.861366  0.802735  0.789774  0.790563  0.827335  ...  0.820754  0.842522   
1  0.854080  0.827517  0.839423  0.828683  0.812323  ...  0.802451  0.829247   
2  0.760256  0.764869  0.754423  0.757319  0.774664  ...  0.747934  0.793632   

     dist52    dist53    dist54    dist55    dist56    dist57    dist58  \
0  0.827061  0.814656  0.813548  0.834271  0.818362  0.823394  0.828642   
1  0.814514  0.834007  0.784510  0.796033  0.821271  0.821276  0.814710   
2  0.759410  0.747319  0.783079  0.759875  0.742791  0.771096  0.759520   

     dist59    dist60    dist61    dist62    dist63    dist64    dist65  \
0  0.869624  0.840927  0.842052  0.859140  0.859804  0.840041  0.835204   
1  0.835696  0.845089  0.810699  0.853660  0.834497  0.828624  0.803920   
2  0.764160  0.758037  0.773802  0.762592  0.762257  0.751729  0.758366   

     dist66    dist67    dist68    dist69    dist70    dist71    dist72  \
0  0.816945  0.852561  0.815066  0.812858  0.844518  0.851627  0.838417   
1  0.821947  0.812763  0.765442  0.795368  0.848876  0.831772  0.828389   
2  0.759480  0.755786  0.762572  0.756787  0.769603  0.756226  0.750196   

     dist73    dist74    dist75    dist76    dist77    dist78    dist79  \
0  0.839868  0.846972  0.851668  0.860816  0.880957  0.845313  0.849569   
1  0.822491  0.810707  0.812499  0.816586  0.828081  0.826785  0.813240   
2  0.757696  0.746333  0.767805  0.759218  0.770810  0.766181  0.768756   

     dist80    dist81    dist82    dist83    dist84    dist85    dist86  \
0  0.870180  0.862554  0.866397  0.874742  0.899475  0.883464  0.879084   
1  0.848113  0.840173  0.814944  0.826645  0.848822  0.818360  0.809330   
2  0.763216  0.766606  0.762598  0.754603  0.767628  0.757145  0.774004   

     dist87    dist88    dist89    dist90    dist91    dist92    dist93  \
0  0.861392  0.874843  0.855589  0.851598  0.849689  0.854272  0.837288   
1  0.827020  0.839443  0.822301  0.831517  0.815193  0.827057  0.813251   
2  0.771965  0.768978  0.784956  0.768604  0.767573  0.759978  0.772354   

     dist94    dist95    dist96    dist97    dist98    dist99  
0  0.841660  0.868675  0.867444  0.836115  0.829863  0.834038  
1  0.799496  0.837142  0.833741  0.791625  0.819392  0.807420  
2  0.767823  0.770422  0.756819  0.762370  0.774629  0.777811  

[3 rows x 101 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to give a solution with creating a database for the data `embeddings`, then calculate the distance with the library `scipy.spatial.distance`, the `df3` is the result you expected.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance
from numpy.linalg import norm
import ast
import time 


start = time.perf_counter()

df = pd.read_csv("https://testme162.s3.amazonaws.com/cosign_dist.csv")

num_colums = len(ast.literal_eval(df["embeddings"][0]))
num_lines = len(df["embeddings"])
data_base_embeddings =np.zeros((num_lines, num_colums))

colums_list = []

for k, i in enumerate(df["embeddings"]):
    embeddings_temp = np.array(ast.literal_eval(i))
    data_base_embeddings[k, :] = embeddings_temp
    colums_list.append("dist" + str(k))
    


dist_matix = distance.cdist(data_base_embeddings, data_base_embeddings, lambda u, v: np.dot(u,v) / (norm(u)*norm(v)))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dist_matix, columns=colums_list)

df3 = df.join(df2)

end = time.perf_counter()

print("Running time: ", str(end - start), "s")
```

Which gives you a running time including loading data :

> Running time:  2.0602212000012514 s

With not including loading data:

> Running time:  0.7129389000001538 s