# Merge dataframes without duplicating rows in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'd like to combine two dataframes using their similar column 'A':

```
>>> df1
    A   B
0   I   1
1   I   2
2   II  3

>>> df2
    A   C
0   I   4
1   II  5
2   III 6
```

To do so I tried using:

> merged = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='A', how='outer')

Which returned:

```
>>> merged
    A   B   C
0   I   1.0 4
1   I   2.0 4
2   II  3.0 5
3   III NaN 6
```

However, since df2 only contained one value for A == 'I', I do not want this value to be duplicated in the merged dataframe. Instead I would like the following output:

```
>>> merged
    A   B   C
0   I   1.0 4
1   I   2.0 NaN
2   II  3.0 5
3   III NaN 6
```

What is the best way to do this? I am new to python and still slightly confused with all the join/merge/concatenate/append operations.

Comment: How do you want it to know that the 4 value in C belonged with the 1 in B?

Comment: @flyingmeatball, I actually do not care about the relationship between columns B and C. I just want 4 to be inserted in the first row of A == 'I' where column C holds no value yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let us create a new variable g, by `cumcount`

```
df1['g']=df1.groupby('A').cumcount()
df2['g']=df2.groupby('A').cumcount()
df1.merge(df2,how='outer').drop('g',1)
Out[62]: 
     A    B    C
0    I  1.0  4.0
1    I  2.0  NaN
2   II  3.0  5.0
3  III  NaN  6.0
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the job!

Comment: @Martijn Yw~ :-)

Comment: @Bharath aha:-)

Comment: @Bharath I learn it from piR  , also he speed it up :-) .....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575486/merge-pandas-dataframe-with-key-duplicates

Comment: @Bharath, Sorry! I missed that topic.

Comment: piR is a legend, he might already have used all possible awesome approaches

Comment: @Bharath yeah , he is :-)