# pandas.merge: Outer join with duplicate keys on both sides results in Cartesian product

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join, cartesian-product, full-outer-join

I have 2 series, `bids` and `asks`, indexed on time.

Some timestamps are duplicated, indicating a price was updated more than once, but the timestamp resolution was too large to capture the difference.

```
                                     bids
2018-06-15 06:00:04.129817+00:00  3525.0
2018-06-15 06:00:04.281829+00:00  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.417908+00:00  3525.0
2018-06-15 06:00:06.537999+00:00  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0 \___ duplicate timestamps
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0 /
2018-06-15 06:00:12.674419+00:00  3525.0

                                    asks
2018-06-15 06:00:04.129817+00:00  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:04.281829+00:00  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.417908+00:00  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00  3527.0 \___ duplicate timestamps
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00  3526.0 /
2018-06-15 06:00:06.537999+00:00  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0 \___ duplicate timestamps
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3527.0 /
2018-06-15 06:00:12.674419+00:00  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:17.333349+00:00  3527.0
```

I would like to merge these 2 series into a dataframe. I use [`pandas.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with an outer join and using both series' indexes for the merge keys:

```
>>> pandas.merge(bids, asks, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
                                    bids    asks
2018-06-15 06:00:04.129817+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:04.281829+00:00  3526.0  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.417908+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00     NaN  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00     NaN  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:06.537999+00:00  3526.0  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:12.674419+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:17.333349+00:00     NaN  3527.0
```

When the same timestamp exists in both `bids` and `asks`, there is a single row with the respective values for each:

```
2018-06-15 06:00:04.129817+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
```

When a duplicate timestamp exists in only one side, that duplicate results in the same number of rows being added, and the other side has `NaN` values:

```
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00     NaN  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00     NaN  3526.0
```

However, when a duplicate timestamp exists in both sides, I get multiple rows, with the cartesian product of both side's values (ie: `A,A`, `A,B`, `B,A`, `B,B`):

```
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0  3527.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0  3527.0
```

What I would like is to have only 2 rows (`A,A`, `B,B`):

```
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3525.0  3526.0
2018-06-15 06:00:09.977950+00:00  3526.0  3527.0
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Would you mind if one of the duplicated rows with `NaN` like `2018-06-15 06:00:05.485926+00:00` would be removed?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, removing one of the duplicate rows with `NaN` in would be a problem, as that means I would lose one of the `ask` values

Comment: The issue is the duplicate values in the bids at that timestamp after the merge: `3525.0, 3525.0`. The bid goes `3525.0`, `3526.0` and the ask goes `3526.0`, `3527.0`. There are 2 unique values for the bids, and 2 unique values for the asks. I would like to have only 2 rows in the result

Comment: duplicated index will have this type of errors when you do merge , try to reset_index and using ['index'] as merge key , you will get what you need

Comment: @WeNYoBen please could you post an answer showing how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

From the answer given in [merge pandas dataframe with key duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575486/merge-pandas-dataframe-with-key-duplicates), it seems that the best way to do this is to create an additional key column that just serves as an arbitrary index to have the outer join merge the nth row of the first DataFrame with the nth row of the second DataFrame (for each original key):

```
df1['cc'] = df1.groupby('key').cumcount()
df2['cc'] = df2.groupby('key').cumcount()
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=["key", "cc"]).drop(columns='cc')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DataFrame.duplicated` to find duplicate rows based on your timestamp column and add 1 microsecond to the duplicate to create distinct rows

Comment: Please could you provide an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
df1.reset_index().merge(df2.reset_index(),on='index',how='outer')
```

Comment: Unfortunately that leaves me in the exact same situation as I already have - there are 4 rows for `06:00:09.977950`, with prices duplicated, as per the cartesian product