# merging dataframes with multicolumn conditions and comparison

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Not sure this is the best or the right way to do what I want.

I have the following df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['1-1-2020', '123','How can I Help?', 'Delivered'], ['1-1-2020', '123','How can I Help?', 'Opened'], ['1-2-2021', '100','New Offer', 'Delivered'],['1-2-2021', '100','New Offer', 'Delivered'],['1-4-2021', '144','Last chance, buy now!', 'Delivered'],['1-4-2021', '144','Last chance, buy now!', 'Delivered'],['2-4-2021', '144','Last chance, buy now!', 'Opened']]),

                   columns=['Date', 'Customer_ID','Subject', 'Status'])


    Date    Customer_ID     Subject              Status
0   1-1-2020    123     How can I Help?         Delivered
1   1-1-2020    123     How can I Help?         Opened
2   1-2-2021    100     New Offer               Delivered
3   1-2-2021    100     New Offer               Delivered
4   1-4-2021    144     Last chance, buy now!   Delivered
5   1-4-2021    144     Last chance, buy now!   Delivered
6   2-4-2021    144     Last chance, buy now!   Opened
```

In this df customer 123 has got an email delivered and then it was opened in the second row.
customer 100 has the email delivered twice
and customer 144 has the email delivered twice one of them opened.

I am trying to track the delivered and open status for each email per customer with last action date.

So, I created two dataframes: one for delivered and one for the opened and merged them on the delivered one to track what is opened.

```
df_del = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Delivered')]
df_open = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Opened')]

d = df_del.rename(columns={'Date': 'Date Delivered'})
o = df_open.rename(columns={'Date': 'last action date', 'Status': 'Open Status'})

w = d.merge(o, on=['Customer_ID','Subject'], how='left')

w
```

This shows:

```
Date Delivered  Customer_ID       Subject            Status     last action date Open Status
0   1-1-2020    123         How can I Help?           Delivered     1-1-2020       Opened
1   1-2-2021    100         New Offer                 Delivered         NaN        NaN
2   1-2-2021    100         New Offer                 Delivered         NaN        NaN
3   1-4-2021    144         Last chance, buy now!     Delivered     2-4-2021       Opened
4   1-4-2021    144         Last chance, buy now!     Delivered     2-4-2021       Opened
```

What I am expecting:

```
Date Delivered  Customer_ID       Subject            Status     last action date Open Status
0   1-1-2020    123         How can I Help?           Delivered     1-1-2020       Opened
1   1-2-2021    100         New Offer                 Delivered     1-2-2021       NaN
2   1-2-2021    100         New Offer                 Delivered     1-2-2021       NaN
3   1-4-2021    144         Last chance, buy now!     Delivered     2-4-2021       Opened
4   1-4-2021    144         Last chance, buy now!     Delivered     1-4-2021       NaN
```

Comment: The Subject/Customer_ID combination isn't unique. You don't have a unique message identifier?

Comment: @JanWilamowski unfortunately no unique identifier for the emails, that is why I am using like a combination of the customer id and email subject to track to some extent the open rate.

Comment: perhaps this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575486/merge-pandas-dataframe-with-key-duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use a pseudo 'order' column:

```
df_del = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Delivered')].copy()
df_open = df.loc[(df['Status'] == 'Opened')].copy()

df_del['order'] = df_del.groupby(['Customer_ID']).cumcount()
df_open['order'] = df_open.groupby(['Customer_ID']).cumcount()

d = df_del.rename(columns={'Date': 'Date Delivered'})
o = df_open.rename(columns={'Date': 'last action date', 'Status': 'Open Status'})

w = d.merge(o, on=['Customer_ID','Subject','order'], how='left')

w['last action date'] = w['last action date'].fillna(w['Date Delivered'])

W
```

Output:

```
  Date Delivered Customer_ID                Subject     Status  order last action date Open Status
0       1-1-2020         123        How can I Help?  Delivered      0         1-1-2020      Opened
1       1-2-2021         100              New Offer  Delivered      0         1-2-2021         NaN
2       1-2-2021         100              New Offer  Delivered      1         1-2-2021         NaN
3       1-4-2021         144  Last chance, buy now!  Delivered      0         2-4-2021      Opened
4       1-4-2021         144  Last chance, buy now!  Delivered      1         1-4-2021         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option with a slightly different pseudo message id generation via [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) and NaN fill via [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html#pandas-series-combine-first):

```
# Create a "message_id"
df['m_id'] = (
    df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Subject', 'Status']).cumcount()
)

# Create Mask For Delivered Status
m = df.Status.eq('Delivered')

# Merge Delivered and ~Delivered
df = (
    df[m].rename(columns={'Date': 'Date Delivered'})
        .merge(df[~m].rename(columns={'Date': 'last action date',
                                      'Status': 'Open Status'}),
               on=['Customer_ID', 'Subject', 'm_id'],
               how='left')
)

# Fill NaN in last action date column
df['last action date'] = (
    df['last action date'].combine_first(df['Date Delivered'])
)
```

`df`:

```
  Date Delivered Customer_ID                Subject     Status  m_id last action date Open Status
0       1-1-2020         123        How can I Help?  Delivered     0         1-1-2020      Opened
1       1-2-2021         100              New Offer  Delivered     0         1-2-2021         NaN
2       1-2-2021         100              New Offer  Delivered     1         1-2-2021         NaN
3       1-4-2021         144  Last chance, buy now!  Delivered     0         2-4-2021      Opened
4       1-4-2021         144  Last chance, buy now!  Delivered     1         1-4-2021         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another way using [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df['last action date'] = df.groupby('Customer_ID').Date.transform('last')
df['op'] = (
    df.groupby(['Customer_ID', 'Subject'])['Status'].cumcount()
)
df['Open Status'] = np.where((df.groupby(['Customer_ID'])\
    .Status.transform('last') == 'Opened') & (df.op==0), 'Opened',np.nan)
df[df.Status=='Delivered'].drop(columns=['op'])
```

**Output**

```
    Date    Customer_ID Subject             Status  last action date    Open Status
0   1-1-2020    123 How can I Help?         Delivered   1-1-2020    Opened
2   1-2-2021    100 New Offer               Delivered   1-2-2021    nan
3   1-2-2021    100 New Offer               Delivered   1-2-2021    nan
4   1-4-2021    144 Last chance, buy now!   Delivered   2-4-2021    Opened
5   1-4-2021    144 Last chance, buy now!   Delivered   2-4-2021    nan
```