# Merge dataframe in R without duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, join, merge

I have a problem in R which is similar to this one:

[merge pandas dataframe with key duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575486/merge-pandas-dataframe-with-key-duplicates)

It shouldn't be that hard to do this in R, but I just don't find the solution.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Providing a reference link to a similar question is helpful but your question should not completely depend on another question. It is expected that you include data and your attempt in R to solve the problem. If the OP in your linked question decides to delete the question then your question becomes meaningless and not useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a sequence column in each data by 'key' and then do a `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(key)) %>% 
   full_join(df2 %>% 
              mutate(rn = rowid(key))) %>%
   select(-rn)
```

-output

```
 key    A    B
1  K0   A0   B0
2  K1   A1   B1
3  K2   A2   B2
4  K2   A3   B3
5  K2   A4 <NA>
6  K3   A5   B4
7  K3 <NA>   B5
8  K4 <NA>   B6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(key = c("K0", "K1", "K2", "K2", "K2", "K3"), A = c("A0", 
"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

df2 <- structure(list(key = c("K0", "K1", "K2", "K2", "K3", "K3", "K4"
), B = c("B0", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: @akrun: I don't understand the sequence column! Could you please explain? Many thanks master!

Comment: @TarJae The OP's data have duplicate for the `by` column i.e. key.  If there are dupes, the join will result in a cartesian join.  To avoid that, we create a group by 'key', `row_number`.  With `data.table`, `rowid` does it more easily without having to do in two steps.  Thus, the join will be `by` the 'rn' and 'key' i.e. now it is a unique by column/s

Answer (score 2):

The answer of akrun is fantastic (see also comments): And I learned again some new stuff:

Most of all using `rowid{data.table}` which is a convenience function for generating a unique row ids within each group.

The `dplyr` only solution would need two steps for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  full_join(df2 %>% 
              group_by(key) %>% 
              mutate(id=row_number())) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  key   A     B    
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 K0    A0    B0   
2 K1    A1    B1   
3 K2    A2    B2   
4 K2    A3    B3   
5 K2    A4    NA   
6 K3    A5    B4   
7 K3    NA    B5   
8 K4    NA    B6
```